# How do I get when an entity was last updated?

Tags: 8, entities

I found from the documentation that to get the created date I can use the    `getCreatedTime()` method.

How do I get when an entity was last updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an entity class that implements [`EntityChangedInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityChangedInterface.php/interface/EntityChangedInterface/8.9.x), [`EntityChangedInterface::getChangedTime()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityChangedInterface.php/function/EntityChangedInterface%3A%3AgetChangedTime/8.9.x) returns the the timestamp of the last entity change for the current translation.

Comment: The trait is an implementation detail that they might or might not use. What's important is that the entity implements EntityChangedInterface.